# Интерфейс или абстрактный класс для Null object pattern?

Tags: c#, архитектура, интерфейс, полиморфизм, дизайн-api

Разрабатываю библиотеку по работе со схемой, где доменная логика следующая:

- есть схема;
- схема может содержать либо таблицу или картинку, но не оба контента одновременно.

Если разработчик, который будет использовать мою либу попытаеться обратиться к таблице (`Scheme.Table.Rows`), а у схемы ее нет, то вместо `NullReferenceException`, я хочу, чтобы выбрасывалась более внятная ошибка. И для было решено реализовать паттерн `Null Object`.

---

### Интерфейс

Сейчас это сделано через интерфейс и вот как это выглядит в проекте:

```
public class Scheme
{
    public ITable Table { get; }
    public IPicture Picture { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="Scheme"/> instance with table content.
    /// </summary>
    public Scheme(ITable table)
    {
        Table = table;
        Picture = new NoPicture();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="Scheme"/> instance with picture content.
    /// </summary>
    public Scheme(IPicture picture)
    {
        Table = new NoTable();
        Picture = picture;
    }
}

public interface ITable
{
    IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; }
}

public class Table : ITable
{
    public IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; }
}

public class NoTable : ITable
{
    public IEnumerable<Row> Rows => throw new Exception("Scheme does not contain a table.");
}

public interface IPicture
{
    Image Image { get; }
}

public class Picture : IPicture
{
    public Image Image { get; }
}

public class NoPicture : IPicture
{
    public Image Image => throw new Exception("Scheme does not contain a picture.");
}
```

---

### Абстрактный класс

А вот как бы это выглядело на абстрактных классах:

```
public class Scheme
{
    public AbstractTable Table { get; }
    public AbstractPicture Picture { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="Scheme"/> instance with table content.
    /// </summary>
    public Scheme(AbstractTable table)
    {
        Table = table;
        Picture = new NoPicture();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="Scheme"/> instance with picture content.
    /// </summary>
    public Scheme(AbstractPicture picture)
    {
        Table = new NoTable();
        Picture = picture;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractTable
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; }
}

public class Table : AbstractTable
{
    public override IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; }
}

public class NoTable : AbstractTable
{
    public override IEnumerable<Row> Rows => throw new Exception("Scheme does not contain a table.");
}

public abstract class AbstractPicture
{
    public abstract Image Image { get; }
}

public class Picture : AbstractPicture
{
    public override Image Image { get; }
}

public class NoPicture : AbstractPicture
{
    public override Image Image => throw new Exception("Scheme does not contain a picture.");
}
```

---

### ВОПРОС

Это очередной случай, когда одно и тоже можно реализовать с помощью интерфейса или абcтрактного класса. **Но с точки зрения логики и дизайна, что правильнее?**

Я обычно использую абстрактный класс, чтобы вынести общий код в отдельное место и самое главное, чтобы отношение между сущностями было типа ***IS***, но что-то затрудняюсь сказать, что **`NoTabel` is `AbstractTable`**.

Comment: Зачем вообще этот паттерн здесь использовать? Почему бы не бросить исключение при обращении к определенному свойству схемы? Например, `public IAbstractTable Table => table ?? throw new Exception("Scheme does not contain a table.")`.
Как этим пользоваться? Везде писать `if (scheme.Table is NoTable) { ... }`?

Comment: @Vlad, все верно, у объекта-схема есть еще одно свойство `Scheme.HasTable => _table is Table`.

Comment: Тогда совсем не понимаю, зачем этот паттерн здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи

> Если разработчик, который будет использовать мою либу попытаеться обратиться к таблице (Scheme.Table.Rows), а у схемы ее нет, то вместо NullReferenceException, я хочу, чтобы выбрасывалась более внятная ошибка.

не нужно использовать паттерн `Null Object`. Достаточно бросать исключения в свойствах:

```
public class Scheme
{
    private readonly Table table;
    private readonly Picture picture;

    public Table Table => table ?? throw new Exception("Scheme does not contain a table.");
    public Picture Picture => picture ?? throw new Exception("Scheme does not contain a picture.");

    // со слов автора, такое свойство имеется
    public bool HasTable => table != null;

    public Scheme(Table table)
    {
        this.table = table ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(table));
    }

    public Scheme(Picture picture)
    {
        this.picture = picture ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(picture));
    }
}

public class Table
{
    public override IEnumerable<Row> Rows { get; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public override Image Image { get; }
}
```

Если нужна абстракция зависимостей от `Table` и `Picture`, добавляем интерфейсы:

```
public class Scheme
{
    ...

    public Scheme(ITable table) { ... }

    public Scheme(IPicture picture) { ... }
}

public interface ITable { ... }

public class Table : ITable { ... }

public interface IPicture { ... }

public class Picture : IPicture { ... }
```

Есть несколько реализаций интерфейсов с общим кодом? Добавляем абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class AbstractTable : ITable { ... }

public class Table : AbstractTable { ... }

public class AbstractPicture : IPicture { ... }

public class Picture : AbstractPicture { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что интерфейсами будет правильнее и вот почему.

Интерфейсы изначально придумывались как промежуточный объект между двумя функциональными объектами.

Абстрактные классы придумывались, чтобы уменьшить код с помощью выноса общих свойств и методов.

В вашем случае, если вы планируете использовать в других проектах, вам проще будет ориентироваться по интерфейсам. И ссылаться проще, и комментарии к интерфейсам будет проще читать.